# Points drawn outside a certain area get placed on perimeter of smaller area

Tags: mapinfo, table, boundaries

I am trying to add points to a table in MapInfo (geologic map) but cannot get points to display in correct location. Are there boundaries for tables? 
How to change this?

I'm using Mapinfo 10.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a MapInfo table can have bounds that limits the data extent of the table.
The benefit of this is to get a better precision of the coordinates.

You can check the bounds of your data with the Coordsys Bounds Manager tool that you can find in the Tool Manager.

If you want to learn more about the tool and bounds, have a look at [this discussion on Li360](https://li360.pitneybowes.com/s/question/0D58000003ali2kCAA/get-out-of-bounds).